# django, how to limit create objects in 1 second?

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this:

```
  1 from django.db import models
  2
  3 class Myclass(models.Model):
  4     sub_date   = models.DateTimeField('datetime', auto_now_add=True)
  5
  6     def __unicode__(self):
  7         return "%s" % self.pk
```

and a function:

```
  9 INV = 1
 10 def create():
 11     if INV > 0:
 12         now = datetime.datetime.now()
 13         ci = now - datetime.timedelta(seconds=INV)
 14         mc = Myclass.objects.filter(sub_date__gte=ci)
 15         print mc
 16         if mc.count() > 0:
 17             raise ValueError("exist!")
 18         else:
 19             Myclass.objects.create()
```

when I run this func in different places same time, it can created more than one objects.
how can I fix this?

Comment: not a best solution as soon as in concurrent threads these action can be done simultaneously. Have You thought about some kind of constraint?

Comment: `v` ? Its undefined variable or it is glabal? Any how you should use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) its more safer.

Comment: Aamir Adnan, sorry about my typing mistake. it's 'mc'.

Comment: To oleg, these code from a voting system, a lot of request from bots. any suggestion?

Comment: I think You need some kind of filter on upper layers not on models layer. this should be done on one of upper layers

Comment: thank you oleg, i will think a about that.

Comment: Require people to login to vote could be a workaround.